# Any TEX / LATEX Tutorial Specifically Covering MikTeX & WinEdit on a Microsoft Windows PC?

Tags: miktex, tutorials

For typesetting my mathematical documents, I have been using MikTeX (for the back-end compilation) and WinEdit (for front end typing), on a Windows system.

However, I often find that I need a tutorial on LATEX document preparation using MikTeX and WinEdit.

There are plenty of tutorials around, but none (of those I know of) seems to deal with MikTeX + WinEdit duo.

Any suggestions please?

Any online books or tutorials specifically on MikTeX + WinEdit?

Comment: Crossposted from math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1943137/264

Comment: @ZevChonoles please note that it is on Math SE that I've first posted this question, and it is on the advice of a Math SE user that I've later posted this question over here. So what's wrong with this?

Comment: If you cross-post something, it's considered common courtesy to say so up-front, to say the very least. Incidentally, the program is called MiKTeX, not MikeTeX. Please fix the spelling.

Comment: I'd expect most tutorials to be editor-agnostic (it doesn't generally matter which editor you type the code in). WinEdt has a "Quick guide" on its website (http://www.winedt.com/download.html#Quick_Guide), and a built-in help, so they might be good references for editor-specific questions. I'm not sure what you're wondering about when it comes to MikTeX. Some advice for maintaining an installation is found in [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447) and [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)